# What's a suitable table design for objects which can be "trashed"

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing a simple media "server" as part of a larger application. I've chosen to adopt similar terminology as the AWS S3 service, i.e Objects and Buckets (i.e files and directories).

I have two tables:

```
cdn_bucket
id, directory
```

and

```
cdn_object
id, bucket_id, filename, is_deleted
```

Other tables in the database can include objects using a foreign key on `cdn_object.id`. This has nice side-effects in that I can specify a constraint to set the field NULL in the event that the object is deleted (or indeed prevent deletion if needed). e.g:

```
blog_post
id, title, body, featured_image
CONSTRAINT: featured_image = cdn_object.id ON DELETE SET NULL
```

I was told once that I shouldn't delete things, ever (*that's an argument for another post, please don't comment on it here*); hence the `is_deleted` flag. To clarify the question, this is what I mean by "trashed", i.e recoverable.

This works great, however I can't leverage the cascading functionality of the constraints (i.e I mark an object as deleted, but the referring table, e.g `blog_post.featured_image` references the old ID).

I was wondering what the SO opinions might be on the following two approaches, or if there's another approach which might be better.

> **1. Join the cdn_object table**
>
> `SELECT bp.*, cdno.id featured_image FROM blog_post bp JOIN cdn_object cdno ON cdno.id = bp.featured_image AND cdno.is_deleted = 0`.
>
> Pro: easy to implement.
>
> Con: every query has to join the `cdn_object` table.

or

> **2. Use a trash table**
>
> Have another table, `cdn_object_trash` and have the code 'move' the row `cdn_object` when it's deleted, triggering all the cascading constraints.
>
> Pro: allows the relational rules to do what they were designed to do
>
> Con: bad by design? Not sure.

My gut feeling tells me I should use the `is_deleted` flag and write code accordingly, but this is a generic class and so I'd prefer to not force the developer to write the join every time if I can configure that logic in the DB.

I hope my situation/question is clear, please ask me to clarify any points if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your third option is to set up a reasonable backup and retention schedule, and use cascading deletes.  While I understand the desire to "never delete anything", abiding by that principle is forcing you to be redundant in your programming choices (option 1) or to figure out how to build a trash table to redundantly store information (option 2; do you build a single table with a string representation of the data, or do you make a trash copy of the schema?).  Both of those choices seem like a lot of work to maintain (over the long haul).

I've worked with variants of both choices, and if those were the only options on the table, option 1 is a bit easier to maintain; however, you have to be EXTREMELY diligent in using it, and you have to make sure that future development efforts live up to that same standard.

Comment: Thanks, you hit the nail on the head - I want to make it as easy as possible for future [less diligent] devs to write queries; and I *know* they won't do it properly. I'm leaning towards option 2 with the trash table effectively being a duplicate of the object table. Writing a few extra lines in the class to handle this I *think* is an acceptable compromise?

Comment: The theorist in me shudders at that compromise, because it will ultimately lead you down the path of making duplicate copies of every table in your database.  You'll need to make decisions as to how and why to roll data out, as well as find ways to lock it down so people don't use it in ad-hoc or future development.

Comment: The practical side of me thinks that it's feasible IF you have a limited number of tables and you have the foresight to build in some maintenance functionality (roll off data older than a certain date, etc.)

Comment: I hear you, and I agree - storing data indefinitely is a recipe for disaster. However I don't plan on applying this approach to EVERY table (sorry, I didn't mean to imply that), just the ones where I want to offer the user the ability to roll back. Everything else can be handled in a regular backup system.